# Add rule for a webform checkbox to autosend email after specified time

Tags: webforms, rules, tokens

Im running D7 with webform.  I have a multstep form, on the last step the user is asked to participate in a future survey.  If they enter their email and check the box to agree, they should receive an email reminder with a  link to a new survey I have created in two weeks from when they agreed.

Im planning to use webform rules, rules, and token modules to create this feature.

Am I going to be able to verify the condition and generate a scheduled email using these modules?  Or do you think I should focus my efforts on a custom module?

Answer (score 1):

You will also need Webform Rules, but once you can react to the submission, you should have no problem getting this going. You'll need to schedule the rule to run in the future and will probably need to add a Rules Component containing the actions to run at that time.

In your triggered rule that reacts to the Webform submission, you need a condition checking if that checkbox was checked and an action that runs the Rule Component you defined earlier. You will want to pass the user object to it (or uid, or email address, or Webform submission - whatever you need) to make sure it works correctly.

I am using Drupal 7 terminology here, but this is achievable in Drupal 6 as well. Just replace "Rule Components" with "rule sets."